# Prolog not printing statements

Tags: prolog, palindrome

I was trying this palindrome program in prolog, the logic works but write operation is not working. So what is the problem in the code?

palin(List1):-
        findrev(List1,[],List2),
        compare(List1,List2).

```
findrev([],List1,List1).

findrev([X|Tail],List1,List2):-
    findrev(Tail,[X|List1],List2).

compare([],[]):-
    write("\nList is Palindrome").

compare([X|List1],[X|List2]):-
    compare(List1,List2).

compare([X|List1],[Y|List2]):-
    write("\nList is not Palindrome").
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. I use SWI prolog. And try replace " with '. Because with `"Something"` it prints it as list of numbers, not as string.